# Como passar um vetor de uma view pra uma controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Eu tenho uma view que printa um relatório na tela. Eu coloquei um botão e estou fazendo uma função pra exportar esse relatório para excel.  Minha dúvida é:

Como enviar esses dados que estão em uma matriz para a minha controller?

Meu botão está assim, Via get eu só consigo passar uma variável.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Exportar', array('controller' => 'reports', 'action' => 'export', $prospects), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'));
```

Comment: Acredito que da mesma maneira que você obteve os dados para montar este relatório nesta *action*, você pode ter estes dados em outra *action* para exportar. Como foi feito neste relatório?

Comment: Eu pensei nisso enviar o meu filtro,   mais aí eu teria o código reescrito? Tem alguma forma de passar um vetor de dados de uma controller pra outra?  Uma outra duvida eu consigo enviar um vetor de uma controller pra outra?

Comment: Não precisa reescrever tudo. Se você tiver um único método privado que faz o processamento e te entrega um vetor, nas duas *actions* (exibir e exportar) você chama esse método e somente a saída vai ser diferente, já que uma vai montar uma view e a outra vai exportar para Excel.

Comment: Eu tenho essa action report_prospects no meu controller e tenho a view report_prospects na minha pasta reports onde eu guardo as views. Mais o meu método pra exportar esses dados estão em uma controller especifica, eu gostaria de saber como passar esses dados de uma controller pra outra. O cakephp tem esse recurso? Se sim, como fazer?